# Why the reference of System.Design.dll not added already in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

When I trying to use "System.Windows.Form.Design" namespace, I have to add reference all the time in new project. Can any tell me about it?

Comment: What project template have you created? And why have you expected that the reference should be there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create different projects in Visual Studio it adds by default different BCL assemblies as references. `System.Design.dll` is not one of them as it is not commonly used by standard apps / developers. That's how the designers decided. You could create your own project type which will already contain the reference and then [export it as project template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185318.aspx).

Comment: maybe worth clarifying that you mean not commonly used *by standard apps / developers* - it is used by the *runtime* all the time ;p

Comment: If I am want to use daily that namespace in new project then what should I do so that it add automatically?

Comment: @MohammadNasserJavaid, create your custom project type and export it as a template. Then use this template to create your projects.

Answer (score 6):

There are *masses* of dlls available just in regular .NET, with tools to cover a wide range of technology niches - and that is *before* you add any external libraries. You wouldn't want *all the available .NET framework* dlls in your project - it would, frankly, make your eyes blister. The IDE adds a small set designed to cover:

- allowing the default application template to build
- some core / heavily-used .NET features
- in the case of 4.0, supporting libraries for certain language features (`dynamic` etc)

It is entirely likely that you will need more references - but *which* references depends on **what you are going to write** - for example, you might need EF, or you might need RSS-handling, etc. You might also choose to *remove* a few of the default ones, if you aren't actually using them (although note that this doesn't affect the result, as the C# compiler will drop unused references automatically - this is just to be tidy).

Tools like resharper can help here, by offering to add both the `using` directive *and* the reference when you enter a type-name that it recognises (but which doesn't currently resolve).